# unable to save applicationHost.config file

Tags: .net, windows, iis, configuration-files

I could not save applicationHost.config file, it says "save failed and it is open in another programs" while I stop IIS service and closed visual studio, any idea?

Answer (score 50):

If you're on a 64-bit architecture and trying to edit with a 32-bit editor (e.g. Notepad++) apparently you can't save the  file. 
Try editing your file with the regular notepad that is shipped with Windows. To be absolutely sure, also run Notepad as an Administrator

Comment: using notepad++ with admin privilege, it was giving me the impression that it was saving my changes. eek

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Notepad++ as admin
2. Open %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
3. Stop IIS
4. Edit and save changes

Answer (score 1):

You do not have sufficient priviledge to modify the file.

Right click on file and click Properties.

Under the Security tab -> check to see if the user account you are logged in with has Modify permission on the file.

If not then Edit the permission and check the modify and Apply these settings.

Now try updating it.

Comment: I have full control on it. but I cant save it yet. Ofcourse there is no tick on Special Permissions checkbox. it is disabled totally.

Comment: I also had this issue yesterday. Although it must do but try this -> After updating permissions (Logged in User), check the permissions again and see if they are updated. If not browse to IIS manager (I used IIS 7), go to Virtual Directory and click Content View (bottom middle)and select the applicationHost.config and right click to "Edit Permissions" and update the same from there. Hopefully this will do.

Comment: I cant find applicationHost.config from where you said. only my website directory is there.

Comment: I just found that it is not required, my original answer did it for me and i updated a file easily, i can't say why it is not working in your case. One thing, make sure you have assigned permissions to the right user. Thanks.

Comment: Ok read this here http://forums.iis.net/t/1175866.aspx which contains a link here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/264/shared-configuration/#07  This is something similar, try it

Comment: thank you dear DnshPly9, i hope it help to solve it, it takes 2 days of my week :(

Comment: In Software, Sometimes things doesnt really work easy, you will be happy once you get it working and u will get it working. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to edit the one in C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer? There's a mirror copy in your Documents folder, under IISExpress\config which I believe is the one you're meant to edit; changes are copied across for you.