# Quartz.net Jobs after IIS Reset or server shutdown

Tags: asp.net, iis, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have used Quartz.Net to schedule some jobs in my ASP.net Application. 
I am using default JobStore I think it is RAMJobStore but I am not sure exactly I only know I didn't config anything about Store.

Well the problem is that I want to store all jobs in DB so that I can run remaining jobs again when server resets or shutdown and start again .

I know I can store Jobs to DB using AdoJobStore but I want to know If my application server restarts and application not running in IIS how those remaining jobs can be triggered again ?

Is there any tutorial about this ? does anyone had some experience about triggering stored jobs after server reset ? any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you are using `AdoJobStore` you just need to start the scheduler again and thats it.

Comment: Well thanks for answer but my application is in iis and think iis has been reset by some admin or so , no one starts application by sending http request , is there any way to activate application again without human interference?

Comment: Im not sure if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11142460/1486443

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET for scheduling. You can develop Windows service or other application types.

Comment: "ASP.net Application." and "always running" to NOT mix...thus using ASP.net Application.for scheduling jobs..is a bad idea. Fortunately, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.   https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/server/Quartz.Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A.  You will use AdoJobStore (as mentioned in comments).

B.  You need to understand and tweak the "misfire" configuration.  There is not a simple "yes" or "no" answer to this question.

http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2009/03/so-you-think-you-understand.html

Since quartz.net is a java port over, you can also find helpful information here

http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html

Here is a sample paragraph (in case that link dies in the future at some point)

> Sometimes Quartz is not capable of running your job at the time when
> you desired. There are three reasons for that:
>
> (1) all worker threads were
> busy running other jobs (probably with higher priority)
>
> (2) the scheduler
> itself was down
>
> (3) the job was scheduled with start time in the past
> (probably a coding error)

The second one "(2)" (in the above quote) is your scenario.

The then goes on to explain scenarios and options.

Things to internet-search if any of the articles disappear in the future.

java'ish

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold

c#

"So you think you understand misfireThreshold"