# Quartz .NET Scheduler not working on client uat environment while it is working locally

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have created a scheduler that runs every 10 minutes to check a table and if any data exists in that table then it sends emails to those persons accordingly. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I installed Quartz and added it in my bin and references also. It is working perfectly in my local and in my testing environment also. I added some logs just to make sure the scheduler is triggering and it inserts data into my table after every 10 minutes.

Now I deployed it on the client environment and the scheduler is not getting trigerred at all. I searched some other questions and it said to add TimeZone in my scheduler but this does not work also.

here is my code

```
  public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailTrigger>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
            (s =>
              s.WithIntervalInMinutes(10)
              .OnEveryDay()
              .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local) //added later
            )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

And EmailTrigger.cs

```
           public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            
            clsEmail objEmail = new clsEmail();
            if (dtLayer.getValueFromStaticConfiguration("EmailTriggerOnApproval", "N") == "Y")
            {
                dtLayer.execute(@"Insert into EmailSendLogs(Message,Description,Date) 
                                 values ('Trigger started 1','Trigger started 1' , GetDate())");

                DataTable dtData = dtLayer.getDataTableFromQuery("select * from EmailSendData where IsSend is null");
                if (dtData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtData.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dtLayer.execute(@"Insert into EmailSendLogs(Message,Description,Date) 
                                 values ('Trigger started 2','Trigger started 2' , GetDate())");

                        string NomineeList = dtData.Rows[i]["NomineeUser"].ToString();
                        string FromEmpid = dtData.Rows[i]["FromEmpID"].ToString();
                        string EmailID = dtData.Rows[i]["EmailID"].ToString();
                        string url = dtData.Rows[i]["URL"].ToString();
                        string Type = dtData.Rows[i]["Type"].ToString();
                        string query = dtData.Rows[i]["EmailDetails"].ToString();
                        string UserID = dtData.Rows[i]["UserID"].ToString();
                        string NotificationID = dtData.Rows[i]["NotificationID"].ToString();
                        string CCMail = dtData.Rows[i]["CCMail"].ToString();
                        string ApprovalCode = dtData.Rows[i]["ApprovalCode"].ToString();
                        string Id = dtData.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();

                        DataTable dtEmailDetails = dtLayer.getDataTableFromQuery(query);
                        ArrayList emailDetails = dtLayer.datatableTOarraylist(dtEmailDetails);
                        emailDetails.Add(ApprovalCode);

                        if (dtLayer.getValueFromStaticConfiguration("SendEmail", "N") == "Y")
                            objEmail.sendMailNewFunction(NomineeList, FromEmpid, EmailID, url, Type, "", emailDetails, UserID, false, null, NotificationID, CCMail);

                        dtLayer.execute("update EmailSendData set isSend='Y' where ID= " + Id + " ");

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    dtLayer.execute(@"Insert into EmailSendLogs(Message,Description,Date) 
                                 values ('Job ran successfully','No approved cases pending' , GetDate())");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dtLayer.execute(@"Insert into EmailSendLogs(Message,Description,Date) 
                 values (" + dtLayer.checkNull(e.ToString()) + ",'Exception Catch',GetDate())");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

JobScheduler.Start();  This function is already there in my global.asax.cs which starts the scheduler

I don't know why my JobScheduler is not getting trigerred. Any suggestions please?

I have deployed the updated patch two times and also restarted the IIS Server. Nothing worked .

Anyone can help me? Nothing has worked till now.

Comment: I assume you checked that `dtLayer.getValueFromStaticConfiguration("EmailTriggerOnApproval", "N")` returns "Y" on the UAT?

Comment: @rene Yes It does return Y

Comment: thats because your IIS web pool is recycling every now and then as compared to ur local server

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140597/iis-app-pool-recycle-quartz-scheduling

Comment: @Allanckw So I just need to change my IIS Settings?  and enable startMode to be AlwaysRunning.? Will this work?

Comment: @Allanckw I did check this link and enabled StartMode as AlwaysRunning but still it did not trigger. Please any other solutions? I really need this to work

Comment: i could give you a solution but its not recommended, see https://www.codeproject.com/articles/12117/simulate-a-windows-service-using-asp-net-to-run-sc?fid=229682&df=90&mpp=25&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&select=4133761&fr=101

Comment: @Allanckw at first I thought that my global.asax.cs page was not updated at the production but I again deployed the code on production and just before this function JobScheduler.Start() in global.asax.cs I madea dummy entry in database just to make sure my page was updated. The entry is there in database. But why is not my function  obScheduler.Start()  getting triggered. I don't understand this?

Comment: i cannot tell what is your issue without seeing code, but i have a similar implementation in production and it is working fine.

Comment: @Allanckw I have pasted my code above. If you can take a look. Its actually working okay in my local.